# How do i get File Explorer working again?

Tags: windows-8.1

Anytime i try opening file explorer, computer just go blank for some minuites. I cant copy and paste any files or folders either. I really need help. Don't know what the problem is.

Comment: is it with any folder or a specific one?

Comment: Its might be a virus infection problem , as malware authors target the Explorer as it gets executed frequently , try to check your OS' system  files integrity , here is a good tutorial that explain it [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_other-system/system-file-check-sfc-scan-and-repair-system-files/bc609315-da1f-4775-812c-695b60477a93)

Comment: What is `go blank`? Is this prank? Is file explorer icon shortcut to monitor off?